# RuntimeError: mixed dtype (CPU): expect input to have scalar type of BFloat16

Tags: python, pytorch, huggingface-transformers

I am trying to use chatglm-6b in my own application so I took the code featured in the [model card](https://huggingface.co/THUDM/chatglm-6b) but I keep getting `RuntimeError: mixed dtype (CPU): expect input to have scalar type of BFloat16`

I tried this code:

```py
from transformers import AutoTokenizer, AutoModel
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("THUDM/chatglm-6b", trust_remote_code=True)
model = AutoModel.from_pretrained("THUDM/chatglm-6b", trust_remote_code=True)
response, history = model.chat(tokenizer, "你好", history=[])
print(response)
response, history = model.chat(tokenizer, "晚上睡不着应该怎么办", history=history)
print(response)
```

Since I don't have Cuda on my computer, I took away the `.half().cuda()

Answer (score 1):

If you remove .half.cuda(), model will default use CPU to do inference.
So you have to algin dtype to float.

Please update code as follow and have a try.

```
AutoModel.from_pretrained("THUDM/chatglm-6b", trust_remote_code=True).to("cpu", dtype=float)
```